# Explode array into columns Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, explode

Hi1, I have a json like beow:

```
{meta:{"clusters":[{"1":"Aged 35 to 49"},{"2":"Male"},{"5":"Aged 15 to 17"}]}}
```

and I'd like to obtain the following dataframe:

```
+---------------+----+---------------+
|              1|   2| 5             |
+---------------+----+---------------+
|  Aged 35 to 49|Male|  Aged 15 to 17|
+---------------+----+---------------+
```

How could I do it in pyspark?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`get_json_object()`** function to parse json column:

***Example:***

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([Row(jsn='{"meta":{"clusters":[{"1":"Aged 35 to 49"},{"2":"Male"},{"5":"Aged 15 to 17"}]}}')])

df.selectExpr("get_json_object(jsn,'$.meta.clusters[0].1') as `1`",
"get_json_object(jsn,'$.meta.clusters[*].2') as `2`",
"get_json_object(jsn,'$.meta.clusters[*].5') as `5`").show(10,False)
```

**"Output":**

```
+-------------+------+---------------+
|1            |2     |5              |
+-------------+------+---------------+
|Aged 35 to 49|"Male"|"Aged 15 to 17"|
+-------------+------+---------------+
```